# tidy evaluation cannot work in function in R

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, tidyeval

**Context**

I am learning tidy evaluation on [this website](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/328769_e8a0152e155b4163b4a54473adcea229.html),
And I see an example:

```
x <- sym("height")

expr(transmute(starwars, bmi = mass / (!! x)^2))
#> transmute(starwars, bmi = mass/(height)^2)

transmute(starwars, bmi = mass / (!! x)^2)
#> # A tibble: 87 x 1
#>     bmi
#>   <dbl>
#> 1  26.0
#> 2  26.9
#> 3  34.7
#> 4  33.3
#> # ... with 83 more rows
```

Then, I imitated the above example in my own code using `sym` and `!!`, but it reported an error.

```
library(survival)
library(rms)
data(cancer)

x = sym('meal.cal')

expr(cph(Surv(time, status) ~ rcs(!! x), data = lung))
# cph(Surv(time, status) ~ rcs(meal.cal), data = lung)

cph(Surv(time, status) ~ rcs(!!x), data = lung)
# Error in !x : invalid argument type
```

**Question**

Why do I use `sym` and `!!` in my code will report an error and how to fix it.

Is it because of the `rcs()`.

Comment: By the way you're reading a very old version of this dplyr vignette. We no longer recommend using `!!` in simple applications. Instead, we now provide the easier `{{` and `.data` patterns. See https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html. However these patterns won't work with base functions, only with tidyverse ones.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use `rlang::inject()` to splice arguments with `!!` into functions that usually don't support tidy evaluation. This saves us from using `eval(expr(...))` and also answers your question why we don't need `rlang::inject()` with `dplyr::transmute()`. The latter already supports tidy evaluation while `cph()` does not.

```r
library(survival)
library(rms)
data(cancer)

x = sym('meal.cal')

rlang::inject(cph(Surv(time, status) ~ rcs(!!x), data = lung))
#> Frequencies of Missing Values Due to Each Variable
#> Surv(time, status)           meal.cal 
#>                  0                 47 
#> 
#> Cox Proportional Hazards Model
#>  
#>  cph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ rcs(meal.cal), data = lung)
#>  
#>  
#>                          Model Tests    Discrimination    
#>                                                Indexes    
#>  Obs        181    LR chi2      0.72    R2       0.004    
#>  Events     134    d.f.            4    R2(4,181)0.000    
#>  Center -0.3714    Pr(> chi2) 0.9485    R2(4,134)0.000    
#>                    Score chi2   0.76    Dxy      0.048    
#>                    Pr(> chi2) 0.9443                      
#>  
#>              Coef    S.E.   Wald Z Pr(>|Z|)
#>  meal.cal    -0.0006 0.0013 -0.48  0.6299  
#>  meal.cal'    0.0007 0.0051  0.14  0.8860  
#>  meal.cal''   0.0010 0.0261  0.04  0.9682  
#>  meal.cal''' -0.0132 0.0676 -0.19  0.8456  
#>
```

Without tidy evaluation we can stay in base R and use `eval(bquote(...))` and splice `x` with `.(x)`.

```r
library(survival)
library(rms)
data(cancer)

x = sym('meal.cal')

eval(bquote(cph(Surv(time, status) ~ rcs(.(x)), data = lung)))
#> Frequencies of Missing Values Due to Each Variable
#> Surv(time, status)           meal.cal 
#>                  0                 47 
#> 
#> Cox Proportional Hazards Model
#>  
#>  cph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ rcs(meal.cal), data = lung)
#>  
#>  
#>                          Model Tests    Discrimination    
#>                                                Indexes    
#>  Obs        181    LR chi2      0.72    R2       0.004    
#>  Events     134    d.f.            4    R2(4,181)0.000    
#>  Center -0.3714    Pr(> chi2) 0.9485    R2(4,134)0.000    
#>                    Score chi2   0.76    Dxy      0.048    
#>                    Pr(> chi2) 0.9443                      
#>  
#>              Coef    S.E.   Wald Z Pr(>|Z|)
#>  meal.cal    -0.0006 0.0013 -0.48  0.6299  
#>  meal.cal'    0.0007 0.0051  0.14  0.8860  
#>  meal.cal''   0.0010 0.0261  0.04  0.9682  
#>  meal.cal''' -0.0132 0.0676 -0.19  0.8456  
#>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @Tim. I am using `rlang::inject()` and `rms::Predict()` jointly, but an error occur. I would appreciate it if you could help me look at it. The question is post at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73878304/inject-function-from-rlang-package-cannot-work-with-predict-function-from-rm).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `eval()`

```
eval(expr(cph(Surv(time, status) ~ rcs(!! x), data = lung)))
```

Comment: Thanks @langtang. It works in my code. But I don't why `transmute(starwars, bmi = mass / (!! x)^2)` works fine without `eval()`. However, I need to wrap my code in `eval()`.

Comment: see @TimTeaFan for nice explanation, and alternative options.