# inject() function from rlang package cannot work with Predict() function from rms package in R

Tags: r, tidyeval, nse, non-standard-evaluation

**Context**

I am learning use tidy eval to write my own function.

If I calculate `hr1` without using tidy eval, the code works fine, such as:

`hr1 = Predict(fit, meal.cal = q, fun = exp, ref.zero = TRUE)`

When I use `rlang::inject()` and `rms::Predict()` jointly to calculate `hr1`, an error occurs, such as:

`hr1= rlang::inject(Predict(fit, !!x = q, fun = exp, ref.zero = TRUE))`

**Question**

How to use `rlang::object()` and `rms::Predict()` correctly jointly?

**Reproducible code**

```
library(survival)
library(rms)
data(cancer)

x = sym('meal.cal')

q = quantile(lung[[x]], probs = c(0.05, 0.35, 0.65, 0.95), na.rm = T)

fit = rlang::inject(cph(Surv(time, status) ~ rcs(!!x), data = lung))

dd = datadist(lung)
options(datadist = 'dd') # Predict() cannot work without set the options

hr1 = Predict(fit, meal.cal = q, fun = exp, ref.zero = TRUE) # Run successful
head(hr1)
# meal.cal      yhat     lower    upper
# 1      338 1.2486497 0.7310498 2.132722
# 2      825 0.9916446 0.7766063 1.266226
# 3     1039 1.0245228 0.8826652 1.189179
# 4     1425 1.0558754 0.6322319 1.763392
# 
# Response variable (y):  
#   
#   Limits are 0.95 confidence limits

hr1= rlang::inject(Predict(fit, !!x = q, fun = exp, ref.zero = TRUE)) # Run failed
# Error: unexpected '=' in "hr1= rlang::inject(Predict(fit, !!x ="
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left-hand side of a named parameter (i.e. `=` inside a call) must be a name, it cannot be an expression. To work around this limitation, you can use [splicing](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/splice-operator.html) here:

```
hr1 = rlang::inject(Predict(fit, !!! setNames(list(q), "foo"), fun = exp, ref.zero = TRUE))
```

In general, ‘rlang’ allows `:=` in the place of `=` for named arguments to work around the R syntax limitation but for some reason `inject` does not support this.

Comment: Thanks @Konrad. But your code didn't work.  The error said: `predictors(s) not in model: c(":=", "meal.cal", "q")`

Comment: @zhiweili Good point, `inject` doesn't seem to support this (for reasons that are not clear to me; looks like an oversight!), see update.

Comment: The `:=` syntax is only available within dynamic dots captured with `list2()` or `enquos()`.

Comment: At the beginnings of rlang, a conventional ggvis syntax was still a possibility. Also we wanted data.table users to be able to metaprogram with rlang. Which is why we made `:=` unquoting opt-in via dynamic dots.

Answer (score 2):

As @Lionel Henry notes in the comments, another workaround is to use a regular `do.call` where we need to supply the arguments in list form and we use that together with `rlang::list2()` which allows the use of `:=` and splicing on the lefthand side:

```r
library(survival)
library(rms)
data(cancer)

do.call(Predict, rlang::list2(fit, !! x := q, fun = exp, ref.zero = TRUE))

#>   meal.cal      yhat     lower    upper
#> 1      338 1.2486497 0.7310498 2.132722
#> 2      825 0.9916446 0.7766063 1.266226
#> 3     1039 1.0245228 0.8826652 1.189179
#> 4     1425 1.0558754 0.6322319 1.763392
#> 
#> Response variable (y):  
#> 
#> Limits are 0.95 confidence limits
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>